# Installing NuGet package in the root directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I've created a **NuGet** package which should not be installed to a particular project but rather to the root directory of the solution.

The installation works fine via command line. I'm wondering why a `packages.config` is not added to the root directory on installation? The problem is that if I run: `nuget list -Source "MySourceName"` is displays `No packages found.`. Here is the problem that an uöpdate of the package would not be possible. What is the best approach in this scenario?

Comment: Usually packages are project-specific. Why do you want to drop files in the solution root?

Comment: Cosider making a Visual Studio extension, NuGet packages apply to projects

Comment: Because it's a tool which can be executed at root level regardless of project.

Comment: I agree with Erik, NuGet packages will be install to a project by default, and it is for projects.